# python mysql connection problem

Tags: python, mysql

This code works fine:

```
import  MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "","bullsorbit")
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("Select * from  table  where  conditions'")
numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)

print 'Total number of Pages :  %d ' % numrows
```

but if I give my IP address

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("192.168.*.*", "root", "","bullsorbit")
```

it will give this error

```
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip address' (111)")
```

Comment: Is your server configured to allow the root to login on a non-localhost connection?

Answer (score 5):

Code 2003 is a [standard MySQL client error](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-client.html):

> Error: 2003 (CR_CONN_HOST_ERROR) Message: Can't connect to MySQL server on '%s' (%d)

I'd guess that your user is not allowed to connect to the MySQL server using an iP-address. What happens if you try a connection usign the MySQL commandline client?

> $ mysql --host=192.168.1.1 -u root bullsorbit

Comment: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.5.23' (111)

Comment: So your problem has nothing to do with Python. You must give the user the permission to connect from the IP address of your local machine.

Answer (score 3):

with localhost you connect via loopback-interface.

with ip-addr you connect - as you connect from extern.

if your server allows only the local (loopback) connection
your ip-addr connection fails. (security!)

look at your mysql config, maybe only local-connections are allowed.

is the skip-networking switch off (in the mysql-conf) ?

```
#skip-networking
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `2003` error, another possibility is that too many connections are being attempted in too short of time.  I noticed this same behavior when I had `127.0.0.1` as my connect string.  First I replaced it with `localhost` which got me further but still the same `2003` error.  Then I saw that if I scaled back the number of calls the error disappeared completely.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

`db = MySQLdb.connect("192.168..", "root", "","bullsorbit")`

try:

`db = MySQLdb.connect(user="root", host="192.168..", db="bullsorbit")`

Password will default to empty string and try the usual identity methods.  Host will also default to localhost on default port.

Comment: hi thank for reply .. i try both i will give same error message